# get all subordinates from user via graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am using Microsoft Graph API (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer). I am trying to get a list of subordinates from the current user. I am able to find the manager, but somehow I am not able to get all subordinates from the manager. I was thinking of 3 possible solutions:

1. Get all subordinates from user (preferred way, so I also directly know if he is a manager, does not work)
2. Get manager ( https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/XXXX/manager) and get subordinates from manager.
3. Get all users, determine manager from current user and do a match for all users. (expensive calls)
4. Make a local copy and do it locally

If somebody has a way to go for option 1 or 2, please tell me. Number 3 is expensive and rather not do it. I guess option 4 is then better.

If somebody knows it, please provide then the example API calls, or a link to the documentation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

so options 1 it is;

the [List DirectReports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-directreports?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) it is!

with https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/XXXX/directReports you will actually found out if the user has subordinates, and therefore know if he is a manager.